# Dynamic programming doubts

Tags: dynamic

In the problem [Minimum number of jumps to reach end](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-of-jumps-to-reach-end-of-a-given-array/), where is the overlapping subproblem?

Answer (score 0):

The overlapping sub-problem is revealed when you invert the direction you traverse the graph, and results in far less calculations to solve for all possible cases.

In the naive solution, every time an element is chosen, you would need to iterate over the possible paths until you hit the end of the array.

However, in the dynamic programming approach, what we are going to do is work backward from our goal.  Instead of figuring out the shortest path to get there, we are going to use the underlying sub problem, which is: **what nodes could I have come from to get to my current node?**  And most importantly, when you apply this approach, you **provide answers for all possible items without duplicate calculations**.

This leads to the following algorithm, which gives you all the answers, for each node:

1. Start at the last item in the array
2. Take the current node, and find all nodes that could have come from there in a single step
3. If this is the first time you have hit that node, store the path you have taken so far as the shortest path between that node and the end
4. If you have already hit this node, discard the result
5. Repeat from step 2 until there are no nodes in the array you haven't hit
6. You now have a list of the shortest paths from any given node to the end of the array